# Matlab axis control?

Tags: matlab, plot

I would like to know if there is any way to creat X axis in this way .

```
       X axis like this way *0, 100, 200, 300,400, 500, 400,300,200,100. 0
```

Comment: Could you explain a little about what you are trying to plot?

Comment: It is an experiment which have X, Y data . X is like force that I applied in this experiment in this sequance * zero till max then back to zero again ... @pandita

Comment: Sounds like you really want time as your x-axis...

Comment: Would `plt.xticks([100,200,300,400,500])` do the job?

Comment: @Dan not really time but funcrion of it .

Comment: @pandita I think you define the xtick but how to define the x axis that should start form Zero and end by Zero as well .

Comment: My point is that it will be very confusing to have the same value repeated on the graph, the x-axis really does represent time and not force. Force is a function of time but time is the independent variable here. I would put your force as maybe labels underneath a time axis.

Comment: In this case I agree with Dan. Plot it either against time or simply plot it on an axis from 0 to 500. Mirroring the axis seems confusing.

Comment: @Dan I got your Idea . In this case ticklabel will be good option .

Answer (score 0):

You may set label to the ticks like that

set(gca,'XTickLabel',{'1','2','3','2','1'}).

See example [here](http://nf.nci.org.au/facilities/software/Matlab/techdoc/ref/plot.html) here under "Specifying Tick Mark Location and Labeling"